# .findOne not passing results to callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This must be a stupid question, but I've bashed my head against the wall for long enough.

Short version: I have a query that returns a result as expected in the Mongo console, but returns no results (or errors) when used through the Mongo NodeJS package.

```
var weatherCacheQuery = {
    'location': {
        '$near': {
            '$geometry': {
                type: 'Point',
                coordinates: [location.coordinates[0], location.coordinates[1]]
            },
            '$maxDistance': 50000
        }
    },
    'retrieved': {
        '$gte': moment().subtract(2, 'hours').toDate()
    }
};
this.db.collection('weather').findOne(
    weatherCacheQuery,
    function(err, doc) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(doc));
    }
});
```

As you can see, nothing overly complex.

If I dump the query object and paste it into a findOne query in the Mongo console, it returns a single result that looks exactly as it should. In the JS, though, the two console.log()s return null.

Somewhat more weirdly, find() with the same query *does* return a result, but not one that I can view because JSON.stringify() complains about it being circular.

Can anyone point out the doubtlessly absurd thing I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using the Node MongoDB driver 2.0?

Comment: Do you get any output if you set `weatherCacheQuery ={}` ?

Comment: @ExplosionPills - package.json shows ^2.0.45.

Comment: @Jaco - Yes, that succeeds (in that it returns data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.findOne`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#findOne) for the node MongoDB driver takes three arguments, and none of them seem to be optional.  Try:

```
this.db.collection('weather').findOne(
    weatherCacheQuery, {}, 
    function(err, doc) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(doc));
    }
});
```

You can also try it with a promise, chain `.then` to `.findOne` and pass the callback to that.

The docs also say that `.findOne` is deprecated and to use.

```
find().limit(1).next
```

You can pass the callback to that.